# Error at install JBoss RHQ - VaultReaderException

Tags: java, linux, jboss, installation, rhq

I am trying to install JBoss RHQ on CentOS. After configuring the `rhq-server.properties` with postgres user and password and calling the command `./rhqctl install`, I received the error below:

```
16:42:41,821 ERROR [org.rhq.enterprise.server.installer.Installer] The installer will now exit due to previous errors: org.rhq.common.jbossas.client.controller.FailureException: Failed to create the RHQ vault: JBAS014749: Operation handler failed: JBAS015804: Error initializing vault --  org.jboss.as.server.services.security.VaultReaderException: org.jboss.security.vault.SecurityVaultException: PB00015: Null Value:Unable to create vault:class is null
   at org.rhq.enterprise.server.installer.ServerInstallUtil.createObfuscationVault(ServerInstallUtil.java:425) [rhq-installer-util-4.13.0.jar:4.13.0]
   at org.rhq.enterprise.server.installer.InstallerServiceImpl.install(InstallerServiceImpl.java:441) [rhq-installer-util-4.13.0.jar:4.13.0]
   at org.rhq.enterprise.server.installer.Installer.doInstall(Installer.java:135) [rhq-installer-util-4.13.0.jar:4.13.0]
   at org.rhq.enterprise.server.installer.Installer.main(Installer.java:59) [rhq-installer-util-4.13.0.jar:4.13.0]
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
   at org.jboss.modules.Module.run(Module.java:260)
   at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:291)
```

Comment: Could you please share some more error logs ?

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you don't have a JBOSS_HOME configured in your env. In this case, you have to unset JBOSS_HOME and run again the install